# Getting error while extracting from list and putting an single attribute furhter into set

Tags: java

I have the below java code now what I am trying to do is that I am getting everything from the repository in the list named Abc list and from that list I am trying to extract an attribute named AbcCode now this tenant code further I want to put in a set of type string so that all tenant code I can have in set  but I am getting not able to do that what I have tried is the below approach please advise is it correct

Comment: I've down voted because this question (edited since I answered) is unintelligable - the `below java code` has been removed and no reference is made to what is failing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong.

First, the `Set` is declared with the wrong generic type, second you're not creating an instance of `Set`, should be:

```
Set<String> tenantCodeSet = new HashSet<>();

for (Tenant tenant : tenantRepository.findAll()) {
    tenantCodeSet.add(tenant.getTenantCode());
}

return tenantCodeSet;
```

It's also worth noting, if you're using Java 8 or greater you can write this in one line:

```
return tenantRepository.findAll().stream()
  .map(Tenant::getTenantCode)
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public Set<String> getTenants(String uuid) throws TenantException {
    Set<String> tenantCodeSet;
    List<Tenant> tenantList;        
    tenantList = tenantRepository.findAll();
    for (Tenant tenant : tenantList) {
        tenantCodeSet.add (tenant.getTenantCode());
    }

 return tenantCodeSet;
}
```

Comment: I've down voted because this is only a partial answer - it's correct that the generic type of `tenantCodeSet` was wrong, but there is no explanation of this.  Additionally the code shown will produce a `NullPointerException` when trying to add the tenant code to the uninitialized `tenantCodeSet`.